# Generate a sphere at each point in a point cloud

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

I have a point cloud in the form of X,Y and Z stored in a txt file as :

```
1.25 4.65 9.15
2.37 8.62 7.59
.
.
.
```

I want to generate a sphere with a determined radius at each point in the point cloud and count the number of points that lie inside that sphere, then store that number in another txt file as:

```
14
27
10
.
.
.
```

which indicates the number of points lying in the sphere in every lap. How can I do this in python?

Comment: is the radius of all spheres the same?

Comment: @Nin17 Yes ... I will determine the radius before going into the for loop then calculate the number of points lying in the sphere in every lap in the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your points as a list of lists, you can do it by summing a generator expression and using `math.dist` to calculate the distances:

```
import math
lst = [[1.25, 4.65, 9.15],
[2.37, 8.62, 7.59]]


r = 5
[sum(1 for j in lst if math.dist(i, j) <= r)-1 for i in lst]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1]
```

Edit:
You could also use a [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html):

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
tree = KDTree(lst)
[len(tree.query_ball_point(i, r))-1 for i in lst]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this will take so long as it's going to calculate the distance between the center and every point in the point cloud and my point cloud exceeds a million

Comment: Yep, its an O(n**2) solution so will scale poorly with increasing the list size. I'll have a think about a better algorithm

Comment: I will be grateful

Comment: I've added another method which hopefully is faster for your data, though I think it depends on how many points there are within each sphere

Comment: you might be able to get it faster if you use the [query_pairs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_pairs.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_pairs) method instead